# The HTTP GET method is not supported by this URL

Tags: jsp, servlets, post, get

I almost finish my project, but i want to go back on an old problem. When I begin it, i create a system of session where users could connect whith a html form.

```
    <form id="form1" method="post"> 

        <input name="myLog" type="text" placeholder="Identifiant">
        <br>
        <input name="myPwd" type="password" placeholder="mot de passe">
        <br>
        <input id="Valider" name="valider" type="submit" value="Connexion">         

    </form>
```

At the origin, i used ''get'' method however for more security, i wanted to use post method without results.Yet I changed in my servlet doGet by doPost like this :

```
     public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException{

        String id = request.getParameter( "myLog" );
        String mdp = request.getParameter( "myPwd" );
      ...
      }
```

But after launch tomcat when I try to go to my form JSP, i have this message which appears to my screen :

> The HTTP GET method is not supported by this URL

I don't understand what the problem is, I already search by myself(lot's of people have this kind of problem but i havn't solutions : it doesn't work).

How can i fix it ?

Thank you !

Archy

Answer (score 0):

Hum...I made a mistake...
I share my solution with you if you have the same problem.

I thought that if I just change doGet by doPost it's a bad way...

It was my login page so when i try to connect the first time, i have not Post value so the servlet was  LOST.

Actually, my form redirects to my login servlet which do traitments (I could do another servlet to solve my problem). So i had to do like this :

```
public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException{
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/LoginPage.jsp" ).forward( request, response );//don't forget it 
    }
    public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException{
            ...
}
```

For furthers precisions, ask me ;)